# Filter string to array char - 'IEnumerable<char>' does not contain a definition for 'ToCharArray'

Tags: c#, linq

Say I have this string `$$A121B` and I want to create an array char of all the digit and letter only.

```
'IEnumerable<char>' does not contain a definition for 'ToCharArray' and no accessible extension method 'ToCharArray' accepting a first argument of type 'IEnumerable<char>'
```

I have this code but it has syntax error at `ToCharArray`

```
var testData = "$$A121B";
var testDataFiltered = (from c in testData
                        where char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)
                        select c).ToCharArray();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code is effectively converted into this:

```cs
var testData = "$$A121B";
var testDataFiltered = testData.Where(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToCharArray();
```

In other words, you're trying to call `ToCharArray` on the result of the `Where` call, which is an `IEnumerable<char>`, not a `string`.

Fortunately, this is easy to fix as LINQ provides a `ToArray` method:

```cs
var testData = "$$A121B";
var testDataFiltered = testData.Where(c => char.IsLetterOrDigit(c)).ToArray();
```

The same code would work with the query expression form as well, but I typically find that when you're just using a `Select` and/or `Where` like this, the "method syntax" is simpler, particularly if you're calling a method on the result, as you are here. (It's definitely worth being comfortable with both forms.)